Multifunction Measurability
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a probability space and $X$ a Polish Space. A multifunction (or set-valued) $F:\Omega \to 2^X$ is a map from $\Omega$ into the subsets of $X$. But when defining measurability, it is always considered multifunctions that take values in closed subsets. See, for example, this link.
There are some measurability equivalences that can be seen in Theorem 1 of the article. Both in this article and in other references it is always assumed that $F$ is a multifunction with non-empty closed images. See Set-Valued Analysis by Aubin and Frankowska Theorem 8.1.4.
When selection theorems are established, they also use multifunctions with closed sets, but I ended up finding a result in Bogachov's book that only assumes multifunction, but requires the graph to be measurable.
I understand that the power set is a "very large" space and that perhaps a selection theorem needs some restrictions, but what is the problem with the proof of equivalences in the definitions of measurability for any multifunction? Why is considering only closed sets important?

One of the characterizations in Theorem 1 at that link is in terms of the distance between points and random sets. This distance cannot differentiate between closed and non-closed sets.

@MichaelGreinecker I thought about that too, but would the equivalences still be true with any multifunction?

You wouldn't even get a measurable graph. Let $N$ be a nonmeasurable subset of $[0,1]$ and consider the set-valued function $\phi$ from $[0,1]$ to its subsets given by $\phi(x)=[0,1]$ for $x\in N$ and $\phi(x)=[0,1)$ otherwise. All the distance functions are constant and, therefore, measurable.
